# pthread_create template function -- Static Casting a template class

Tags: c++, templates, casting, callback, pthreads

I don't know if more information is needed than the code below, but if more is needed just say so and I will post the remaining code. When compiling I am getting the following error:

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W  -I../../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:4:
TimerManager.h: In function 'void* create_pthread(void*)':
TimerManager.h:17: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'TimerManager'
TimerManager.h:17: error: expected '(' before 'TimerManager'
TimerManager.h:17: error: expected ';' before 'TimerManager'
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

---

What do I need to change below to get rid of these errors?

---

```
template<class Object>
void *create_pthread(void *data)
{
  typename TimerManager<Object> *tm = static_cast<TimerManager<Object> *>(data);
  return data;
}

...

template<class CallObject>
class TimerManager {
    ...
};

...

template<class CallObject>
TimerManager<CallObject>::TimerManager() :
  m_bRunning(false),
  m_bGo(false),
  m_lMinSleep(0)
{
  int mutex_creation = pthread_mutex_init(&m_tGoLock, NULL);
  if(mutex_creation != 0) {
    throw TimerManager::TimerError(std::string("Failed to create mutex"));
  }

  int mutex_cond_creation = pthread_cond_init(&m_tGoLockCondition, NULL);
  if(mutex_cond_creation != 0) {
    throw TimerManager::TimerError(std::string("Failed to create condition mutex"));
    return;
  }

  int thread_creation = pthread_create(&m_tTimerThread, NULL, create_pthread<CallObject>, this);
  if(thread_creation != 0) {
    throw TimerManager::TimerError(std::string("Failed to create thread"));
    return;
  }
  m_bRunning = true;
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 17 (the one with the errors?)

Comment: typename TimerManager<Object> *tm = static_cast<TimerManager<Object> *>(data);

Comment: Wait - has `TimerManager` been declared before your `create_pthread` function?

Comment: Nope forgot the forward declaration. Just caught that a sec ago. Post the solution and Ill give you the points

Comment: The immediate error is the excess `typename` in front of the type. It is neither needed nor allowed. Also.note that you can only use functions C linkag  e as arguments of `pthread_create()` (i.e. one declared as `extern "C"`). Function templates can't be declared to have C linkage.

Comment: I understand the extern "C" portion of becuase of the use of the implicit this pointer passed to C++ methods and functions. However don't global functions support the __cdecl calling convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that, given the ordering you have of the declarations, the `TimerManager` class template hasn't been declared prior to your definition of `create_pthread`.  As a result, the compiler reports an error because `TimerManager` isn't in scope.  Reordering the functions should fix that.

Also, you don't need a `typename` in the line

```
typename TimerManager<Object> *tm = static_cast<TimerManager<Object> *>(data);
```

`typename` is only necessary if you are accessing a nested type inside of `TimerManager<Object>`.  You should be able to remove it without any problems.

Hope this helps!